# Does it matter which 24v line I use to splice a common wire from?

Tags: electrical, hvac, thermostat, boiler, thermostat-c-wire

I have a RayPak boiler that currently has a W and R wire only.  In wall i have a 5 connector thermostat cable so I have three extra wires I can connect to.

I'm a little unclear if it matters if i splice into the yellow line or the red line that I drew on the picture.  Its much easier to access the yellow but I'm having trouble figuring out from this diagram where the R and W wires that go to the thermostat are, also I'm assuming that to get the power flowing correctly the C needs to come off one of these terminals and not the other.  Is that correct?

Any guidance is appreciated.  I'm attempting to install an Ecobee3 which mentions here that I can could pull a new 24v wire to install it: https://ecobee.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/227874667

Perhaps a better question is which of the 24v lines is actually the common one in this diagram?

[image]

Comment: You already posted this. Please stick with to your original post and post any updates to that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pulling a C wire off a 24v transformer output](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/103511/pulling-a-c-wire-off-a-24v-transformer-output)

Comment: Original post was deleted.

Comment: The `BL` wire; which you marked with a yellow line, should be the `C` wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformer has 2 terminals, commonly called R and C.  For passive thermostats, the R terminal goes to the thermostat.   The "C" wire **is the other one**.

What's happening is that the smart thermostat needs power, which it gets by attaching to both sides of the transformer.  It already has access to one side (i.e. the R wire).  It needs the other.   So it's the one it's not already getting.

You could try a blind guess.  Try attaching your C wire to either side of the transformer.  If you get the wrong side, there'll simply be 0 volts between R and C, and the thermostat won't get power.  If you get it right, there'll be 24 volts AC between R and C and happy thermostat.  This will only go badly wrong if  you attach to the wrong transformer, or wrong side of the transformer.

Comment: It took me 3 tries - but turns out the yellow wire - which i stupidly marked with a red line is the one to use!